# How to set parameterMap function globally for Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I want to inject this code globally in all `parameterMap` functions for all Kendo data sources:

```js
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key] instanceof Date) {
        // Convert the date object to a string using a standard ISO-8601 format
        data[key] = kendo.toString(data[key], "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I dont think that is possible. Each widget creates a new instance of DataSource's object. Do you create kendo's widgets directly by using, e.g `$('#grid').kendoGrid()` or you have wrappers to do it?

Comment: I am actually using ASP.NET Core so I use wrappers for them.